# Angular 15 and PrimeNG 15 - When resizable columns together with table column grouping columns don't resize as desired

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

I'm developing a solution using Angular (v.15) and tables from PrimeNG (v.15). I'm using attributes that make columns resizable, table column grouping and table expansion. When only using `[resizableColumns]="true"`  and the other two attributes on default the resizing works as desired. But when adding table column grouping (`colspan="x"`) and column resize mode (`columnResizeMode="expand"`) in the table it seems to introduce a bug that doesn't resize the column as desired. When resizing the columns (with all three mentioned attributes)  all columns seems to be affected by the resizing of one column.

Below is a StackBlitz using the the three fundamental attributes (resizable columns, table column grouping and column resize mode set to expand) where you can see and try the error for yourself.
[Link to StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablecolresize-demo-q9qwaj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Is there any solution or should one contact PrimeNG directly?

I've been trying to add and remove different attributes to see when it works and see what attributes that play along together. I want the columns to resize to the desired size without resizing the other columns.